# If $f'(x) = 2 - \frac{f(x)}{x}$ and $f(1)\ne1$, find the following

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow R$ be a differentiable function such that $f'(x) = 2 -
\dfrac{f(x)}{x}$ and $f(1)\ne1$. Find following

i) $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}f'\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$

ii) $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}xf\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$

iii) $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}x^2f'(x)$

iv) Find range of $f(x)$ for $x\in(0,2)$

My attempt is as follows:-

$$xf('x)=2x-f(x)$$

Integrating both sides

$$\left(x\int f'(x)\right)-\left(\int\int f'(x)\right)=x^2-\int f(x)$$
$$\left(x\int f'(x)\right)-\left(\int\int f'(x)\right)=x^2-\int f(x)$$
$$xf(x)-\int f(x)=x^2-\int f(x)$$
$$xf(x)=x^2+c$$
$$f(x)=x+\dfrac{c}{x}\tag{1}$$

$$f'(x)=1-\dfrac{c}{x^2}\tag{2}$$
$$f(1)\ne1$$
$$1+c\ne1$$
$$c\ne0$$

**Part I:**

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}f'\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}1-cx^2=1$$

**Part II:**

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}xf\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}x\left(\dfrac{1}{x}+cx\right)$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}1+cx^2=1$$

**Part III:**

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}x^2f'(x)$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}x^2\left(1-\dfrac{c}{x^2}\right)=-c$$

So we can only say $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}x^2f'(x)\ne0$ as $c\ne0$

**Part IV:**

Case $1$: Assuming $c>0$

As $x>0,\dfrac{c}{x}>0$

$$A.M\ge G.M$$
$$x+\dfrac{c}{x}\ge2\sqrt{c}$$
$$f(x)\ge 2\sqrt{c}$$

As $c>0$, we can only say that $\forall$ x in the domain, $f(x)>2$

**I am not able to find particularly anything for $x\in(0,2)$**. **Any inputs?**

Case $2$: Assuming $c<0$

As we know, $f'(x)=1-\dfrac{c}{x^2}$

$$1-\dfrac{c}{x^2}=0$$
$$x^2=c$$

So either $f'(x)$ cannot be zero anywhere or $c$ cannot be negative.

**Not able to find anything other than this, any inputs?**

Answer (score 1):

Part IV: the function is continuous on $(0,2)$ so its range is an interval. For $c <0$ you can see that $f$ is increasing so its range is $(-\infty, 2+\frac  c 2)$. For $c \geq 0$ the function has  a minimum value at $x =\sqrt c$ and the range is $(2\sqrt c,\infty)$.

Comment: @user3290550 The limit as $x \to 0$ is $-\infty$ when $c<0$. And the supremum is $2+\frac c  2$.